# Do CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM give really random number?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Is there any chance that this query will give the same number? If yes then how to make it truly random?

```
select ABS(CAST(CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(8) AS bigint))
```

Comment: No.  All algorithms on digital computers produce pseudo-random numbers.  This is quite sufficient for almost all purposes.  It think particular physics is the best place to go for real randomness.

Comment: Also, random <> unique.

Comment: It depends on what you mean by "the same number". There are 2^63 unique numbers under this scheme, but you would expect collisions with far fewer than 2^63 numbers generated (this is the well-known birthday problem). If you need *uniqueness*, use a GUID (`UNIQUEIDENTIFIER`).

Comment: Roll a six-sided die 10 times and you'll get repeats. 8-byte, or `BigInt`, expressions give your die 2^64 sides. What do you think will happen if you "roll" your code 2^65 times?

Comment: @HABO: well, for most systems, it would mean either you or the system die of old age. 2^65 nanoseconds is 1170 years. The real problem is duplicates with *fewer* than the maximum number of "rolls". This is why a `BIGINT` as an `IDENTITY` would be fine in most designs, but not necessarily fine when generated randomly.

Comment: An answer according to [Ask Marilyn](https://parade.com/865322/marilynvossavant/can-slot-machines-generate-truly-random-results/) and a source for [HotBits](https://www.fourmilab.ch/hotbits/) based on "particular" physics.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any chance that this query will give same number?

Yes.  But you can always store values in a unique index, and fail or retry on a collision.  With 64bits of randomness you can generate a few million values with only a small probability of a collision.

See, eg

[image]
https://preshing.com/20110504/hash-collision-probabilities/

Comment: I see these numbers cited a lot. Especially by those excited about using Data Vault as a Data Warehouse design. 
They apply when you have 1 number & want to see if it will collide with another.
A typical corporate DW is likely to have 2 Billion rows in the table. 
Suddenly the odds of collision become; 32 bit = collision on every load. 64 bit = seems to happen every few months. 
Every year people get eaten by sharks. Many people have had a meteor hit their roof. (usually small ones), lots of people win the lottery. Thus your collision detection & correction needs to work well.

Comment: You are mistaken.  These are the odds of having any collision for perfect hashes.  Eg the odds of two 32bit hashes colliding is not 1 in 100 million, it's 1 in 4 billion. For 10 integers you have 45 pairs, which increases the odds of a collision to about 1 in 100 million, as shown in the chart.

Comment: OK, I can see how my text leads to that understanding. It may been better to say "a new number collides with another number from the existing set.". 
The point remains, that while the odds seem unlikely, Collisions do happen in Datawarehouses using hash-based keys. And the design shouldn't ignore it as unlikely.

Comment: Agree.  You should plan on managing it like the inevitable, occasional failure in a data warehouse load process.